# Getting error on refresh with d3 and nvd3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization, nvd3.js

I am trying to do some visualizations using d3 and nvd3, as html. 
All visualizations were proper before a couple of days. When i check those visualizations today,visualizations are coming up sometimes and not coming sometimes. But upon refresh, I'm getting `random syntax errors and reference errors`.

It happens same with the examples came with d3 and nvd3 libraries.

In each refresh, getting errors in different lines in d3.js, nvd3.js, etc.,

Looking strange.

What might be going wrong. What should i try to explore?

Comment: Try different browsers/paste here some **specific** errors/exceptions. Examples [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) are working?

Comment: Are you getting libraries from your own server or from a CDN? Maybe lock the libraries to a specific version?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu: Tried with different browser also. And tried with d3 examples. Showing `syntax errors` and in each refresh, error in different lines of d3.js or nvd3.js

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate: getting libraries from own server. Same version, same code..

Comment: Then I expect the dataset you are working with has changed. You will have to see what the difference is between the old data and what you are trying to process now.

Comment: Please copy/paste here some of those `syntax errors` you get.

Comment: I'm getting visualizations. If refreshed, I'm getting even `d3 not defined` and `nv not defined`. And on some refresh, getting back the visualizations also. Not understanding whats going worng. Will it be a virus problem?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu: `SyntaxError: return not in function      d3.vs.js:8239`, `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement    nv.d3.js:4715`, etc

Comment: I tend to believe there's a problem with how you're referencing those scripts. Are you initializing your app logic when document has finished loading? Could you try create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: this sounds like a loading order issue. Sometimes d3 has been loaded before nv.d3 is loaded and sometimes it isn't. Test for d3 before trying to init. something like https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1386569

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu, @Benjamin: The issue is because of a Malware, `ScanTack` which got installed somehow. It took control over all the browsers and settings and was creating pop-up ads in the browser. When i removed that malware, things started working well, as usual. But struggled a lot to find out the reason. Thanks for your help guys :) Really appreciate your timely response.